# Android Version Conflict for Google Services

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, version, firebase-analytics

I've searched for a lot of solutions to this, but none fit my exact case. I am getting this error on Gradle Sync:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.4.2.

this is in my build.gradle (app) dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

and this is in my Project level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Also Important:**
It shows a red line under this line:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
```

The message I'm getting if I hover over it:

> All gms/firebase libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 11.8.0, 11.4.2. Examples include com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0 and com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:11.4.2

I don't even have an analytics dependency!

What do I do?

**Already tried solutions:**

If I try to change my `com.google.android.gms` version, it will throw me a lint saying not to bundle my entire play services in the dependencies. And it also doesn't change the firebase error I'm getting.

Changing firebase to 11.4.2 will throw a lint error.

Changing google play services version to 3.1.1 or below will do nothing.

Comment: share your whole **`Build.Gradle`** with quetion

Comment: @Nilu check the edited answer above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I am not wrong, Google services have the dependency on the firebase. I think both are conflicting

check this [firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup](http://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) and adjust google services and firebase dependency versions

Also, make sure you have this at the bottom of your `build.gradle (app)` file:

`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

Comment: Sure, I could do that. But it throws me a lint error. Saying that there's a new version available. Isn't there any way to do without downgrading the version?

Comment: In that case, you need to upgrade google services dependency which matches firebase 11.8.0. Or try addding both latest version. That should solve the problem

Comment: My google services version is 3.1.2 - the latest. How do i change to `com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0` without it throwing me a lint error.

Comment: try changing google services to com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1

Comment: Just because I ignored it and maybe other people might:
`// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM ... apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' `
... very important

Answer (score 0):

You might have some third party library in your project using the `com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:11.4.2` version of Analytics. Try to find that.

Comment: Paste both you app level and project level gradle files.

Comment: Are you sure you have nothing in your libs folder and also other modules in your project?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it from 11.8.0 to 11.4.2 works for me.
old values

```js
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
```

new values

```js
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
```

Answer (score -4):

change this

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
```

to

```
compile'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
```

and make sure that in your applevel build.gradle  all google and firebase dependency version should be the same.

it doesnt works try removing google dependency from applevel build.gradle

Comment: This doesn't do anything. And, I believe `implementation` is the recommended new way to do it.