# dependencies collision android studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies, build.gradle

I have dependencies collision in android studio. This is the dependencies at build.gradle app:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.github.medyo:android-about-page:1.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.8.0'
compile 'com.github.medyo:android-about-page:1.2.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'


compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'

compile ('com.dji:dji-sdk:4.4.1')
provided ('com.dji:dji-sdk-provided:4.4.1')
```

}

I've tried to change from 11.8.0 to 11.4.2 by this question:
[Android Version Conflict for Google Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48094051/android-version-conflict-for-google-services)

But it didn't work. 
What can I do in order to solve it? Thanks

The message:

```
Found versions 27.0.2, 25.2.0, examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.2 and com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.2.0
```

Comment: Did you try my solution? Did it solve your issue?

Comment: Just did. It worked, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then, you need to explicitly add them.

In a project of mine I had a similar problem in the past. And I need to force those library version to the wanted one.

```
...
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.0.2'
...
```